# How to make rest service call (external url's) using dojo?

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo

I need to call a simple rest service in a different domain with dojo:

```
http://webservices-test/Limit/{mandant}/{userid}/{amount}/{date}
```

As return I get a **boolean/String**.

What do I have to do to call a **REST service** and how do I get the result with dojo?
I can't use `dojo.xhrGet`, since it has some limitation with **external url's** (reference guide).

Hope you can help me

Comment: probably a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549972/cross-domain-rest-dojo-call

Comment: maybe - but there is no answer so far and I think it should be possible. I tried dojo.io.script.get(), but I don't get a json reply.

Comment: No. Your server side will have to connect to the other domain and provide you the result. The rule is that, a view (front-end) that belongs to a domain shall communicate only with that domain. not external.

Comment: But this works:'dojo.io.script.get({
url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web",
callbackParamName: "callback",
content: {
 v: "1.0",
 q: "dojo toolkit"
},
load: function(data){          console.log("Load data Google: " + dojo.toJson(data, true));},
error: function(error){
 console.log("An unexpected error occurred: " + error);
}});' What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at dojo/request?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request.html

I think you could easily do something like:

```
request.get("http://webservices-test/Limit/{mandant}/{userid}/{amount}/{date}").then(function(result) {
  //do whatever here
});
```